# Log file is not generating while I am starting a spring boot application as system service in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, centos, log4j

I have created a system service for spring boot application in Linux. When I am starting that service to run the application, log file is not generating. But the same application I am running using normal java command (java -jar application_name.jar), then log file is creating successfully. Can any one please help me out?

Notes:

1. I am using log4j for logging.
2. I have tried this thing on centOS and Photon Linux distribution.
3. One thing I observed that, every time when I am running application using normal java command, a new log file is generating. Same I am expecting through running application as a system service.

Comment: You'll need to include the code as well.

Comment: @Nicholas Which part of code you need?

Comment: See [mcve] for details on which code you need to include.

Answer (score 0):

Log4J requires configuration, typically through a file of some sort. I suspect you did not specify where to put the logs. Read the Log4J documentation for details.